# preventDefault não funciona com função onclick no botão

Tags: javascript, ajax

preventDefault não funciona segue o codigo:

```
function updateCliente(e) {
    var url2 = "con_cliente.php" 
    var url = "update/update_cli.php"; 
     if (confirm('Tem certeza que quer cadastrar o cliente?')){ 

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#form_cli").serialize(),
           success: function(data)
    {

        $("#alterafade").fadeOut(800, function(){
        $("#alterafade").load(url2).fadeIn().delay(2000);
               });

               //utilizar o dado retornado para alterar algum dado da tela.
           }

         });
         e.preventDefault();// esse comando serve para previnir que o form realmente realize o submit e atualize a tela.
     }


}
```

form

```
 <form id="form_cli" >
     <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
       <strong> Nome do Cliente</strong>
       </div>
       <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name"  value="<?php echo $row['nome_cliente']; ?>"  />
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-user">
        </i>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <strong>Nome Fantasia ou arte:</strong>
       </div>
       <input name="nome_fant" type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_fant" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['nome_fant_cli'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" />
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-cube">
        </i>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
      <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <strong>Email</strong>
       </div>
       <input name="email_cli" type="text" class="form-control" id="email_cli" value="<?php echo $row['email_cli']; ?>" />
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-cube">
        </i>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <strong>Endere&ccedil;o:</strong>
       </div>
       <input name="end_cli" type="text" class="form-control" id="end_cli" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['endereco_cli'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" />
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-map">
        </i>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <strong>Numero de contato:</strong>
       </div>
       <input name="tel" type="text" class="form-control" id="tel" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['telefone_cli'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" />
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-phone-square">
        </i>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <strong>CEP</strong>
       </div>
       <input name="cep" type="text" class="form-control" id="cep" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['cep_cli'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" />
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-map-o">
        </i>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <strong>CPF/CNPJ:</strong>
       </div>
       <input name="cpf" type="text" class="form-control hibridCpf" id="hibridCpf" value="<?php echo $row['cpf']; ?>"/>
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o">
        </i>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="id_cli"  value="<?php echo $row['id_cli']; ?>" />
           <button class="btn btn-success" name="submit" type="submit" onclick="updateCliente()">
        Salvar
       </button>
    </form>
```

Comment: prontinho acabei de colocar

Comment: Troque o tipo do botão : `<button class="btn btn-success" name="submit" type="button" onclick="updateCliente()">`

Comment: funcionou muito obrigado

Comment: Acho que não precisa mais do `preventDefault()`

Comment: não precisa mesmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme esclarecido nos comentários o problema ocorre com o botão de envio do formulário:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" name="submit" type="submit" onclick="updateCliente()">
   Salvar
</button>
```

Segundo a documentação [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) a propriedade `type` informa ao navegador qua o comportamento padrão desse botão:

- `submit`: O botão envia os dados do formulário ao servidor. Esse é o padrão se o atributo não for especificado ou se o atributo for alterado dinamicamente para um valor vazio ou inválido.
- `reset`: O botão redefine todos os controles para seus valores iniciais
- `button`: O botão não possui comportamento padrão e não faz nada quando pressionado. Ele pode ter scripts do lado do cliente associados aos eventos do elemento, que são acionados quando os eventos ocorrem.

No caso o a propriedade `type` associada ao botão é `submit`.

Para corrigir o problema basta modificar propriedade `type` de `submit` para `button`, fazendo com que ao ser pressionado o botão invoque o evento associado a ele e tornado desnecessário, nesse caso, a chamada a [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) que pode seguramente ser removida do código.

```
<button class="btn btn-success" name="submit" type="button" onclick="updateCliente()">
   Salvar
</button>
```

Aplicando o reparo no seu código *Javascript*:

```
function updateCliente(e) {
    var url2 = "con_cliente.php" 
    var url = "update/update_cli.php"; 
     if (confirm('Tem certeza que quer cadastrar o cliente?')){ 

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#form_cli").serialize(),
           success: function(data)
    {

        $("#alterafade").fadeOut(800, function(){
        $("#alterafade").load(url2).fadeIn().delay(2000);
               });

               //utilizar o dado retornado para alterar algum dado da tela.
           }

         });             
     }
}
```

E em seu código *HTML*:

```
<form id="form_cli" >
     <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
       <strong> Nome do Cliente</strong>
       </div>
       <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name"  value="<?php echo $row['nome_cliente']; ?>"  />
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-user">
        </i>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <strong>Nome Fantasia ou arte:</strong>
       </div>
       <input name="nome_fant" type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_fant" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['nome_fant_cli'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" />
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-cube">
        </i>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
      <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <strong>Email</strong>
       </div>
       <input name="email_cli" type="text" class="form-control" id="email_cli" value="<?php echo $row['email_cli']; ?>" />
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-cube">
        </i>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <strong>Endere&ccedil;o:</strong>
       </div>
       <input name="end_cli" type="text" class="form-control" id="end_cli" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['endereco_cli'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" />
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-map">
        </i>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <strong>Numero de contato:</strong>
       </div>
       <input name="tel" type="text" class="form-control" id="tel" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['telefone_cli'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" />
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-phone-square">
        </i>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <strong>CEP</strong>
       </div>
       <input name="cep" type="text" class="form-control" id="cep" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['cep_cli'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" />
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-map-o">
        </i>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <strong>CPF/CNPJ:</strong>
       </div>
       <input name="cpf" type="text" class="form-control hibridCpf" id="hibridCpf" value="<?php echo $row['cpf']; ?>"/>
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o">
        </i>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="id_cli"  value="<?php echo $row['id_cli']; ?>" />
           <button class="btn btn-success" name="submit" type="button" onclick="updateCliente()">
        Salvar
       </button>
    </form>
```